# Supabase session object is missing provider_token after authentication

Tags: oauth, supabase

I am trying implement authentication with Notion provider by using Supabase in a browser extension. After authentication, I receive `access_token`, but I don't get `provider_token`.

[Here](https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/5787#discussioncomment-5470051) is how I implemented authentication flow.

**supabase.ts**

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'
import qs from 'qs'

const supaUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_URL
const supaANONKey = import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY
export const supabase = createClient(supaUrl, supaANONKey, {
  global: {
    fetch: (...args) => fetch(...args),
  },
})

export const extensionSupabaseLogin = async () => {
  const redirectUri = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL('supabase-auth')
  const options = {
    provider: 'notion',
    redirect_to: redirectUri,
    ux_mode: 'redirect',
  }
  const url = `${supaUrl}/auth/v1/authorize?${qs.stringify(options)}`

  const originalTab = (await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }))[0]
  const authenticationTab = await chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'about:blank' })
  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function notionAuthHook(tabId, _changeInfo, tab) {
    if (tabId === authenticationTab.id && tab.url?.startsWith(redirectUri)) {
      const splitUrl = tab.url?.split('#')[1]
      // Prompt user to sign in again if unparsable (error)
      if (!splitUrl) {
        console.error('Unparsable sign-in URL', tab.url)
        return
      }
      // Parse tokens from URL
      const authResult = qs.parse(splitUrl)
      const refreshToken = authResult.refresh_token as string
      const accessToken = authResult.access_token as string

      // Prompt user to sign in again if no access_token (error)
      if (!refreshToken || !accessToken) {
        console.error('No access token or refresh token returned', authResult)
        return
      }

      ;(async () => {
        const { error } = await supabase.auth.setSession({
          access_token: accessToken,
          refresh_token: refreshToken,
        })
        if (error) console.error(error)
      })()

      chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(notionAuthHook)
      chrome.tabs.remove(tabId)
      if (originalTab?.id) {
        chrome.tabs.update(originalTab.id, { active: true })
      }
    }
  })
  // Send users to the sign-in flow
  if (authenticationTab.id) {
    await chrome.tabs.update(authenticationTab.id, { url: url })
  }
}
```

**background.ts**

```
import { Client } from '@notionhq/client'
import { extensionSupabaseLogin, supabase } from './supabase'

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.action === 'signIn') {
    extensionSupabaseLogin();
  } else if (request.type === 'GET_NOTION_PAGE') {
     const { accessToken, ...options } = request.options as GetPageNotionOptions
     debugger
     if (!notionClient) {
       setNotionClient(accessToken)
     }
     if (notionClient) {
       const response = await notionClient.pages.retrieve({ ...options })
       sendResponse({ type: 'SUCCESS', data: JSON.stringify(response) })
     }
  }
});

let notionClient: Client | null = null

const setNotionClient = (notionCode: string) => {
   notionClient = new Client({
      auth: notionCode,
   })
}

const storeNotionIdentity = async (notionIdentity: { accessToken: string; refreshToken?: string }): Promise<void> => {
  setNotionClient(notionIdentity.accessToken)
  await chrome.storage.local.set({
    notionIdentity,
  })
}

const storeNotionUser = async (user: User): Promise<void> => {
  await chrome.storage.local.set({
    user,
  })
}

const setupAuthListener = () => {
    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(async (event, session) => {
      if (event === 'SIGNED_IN' || event === 'USER_UPDATED') {
        //this user has just signed in or their session has been updated
        console.log('user is signed in :', session)
        if (session?.access_token && session?.refresh_token) {
          debugger
          await storeNotionIdentity({ accessToken: session.access_token, refreshToken: session.refresh_token })
        }
        if (session?.user) {
          await storeNotionUser({
            name: session.user.user_metadata?.name,
            fullName: session.user.user_metadata?.full_name,
            email: session.user?.email ?? session.user.user_metadata?.email,
            userId: session.user.id,
          })
        }
        if (typeof loginTabId === 'number') {
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage(loginTabId, `notion login success`)
        }
      } else if (event === 'SIGNED_OUT') {
        //the user has just signed out or their account has been deleetd
        console.log('user is signed out')
        loginTabId = null
        await chrome.storage.local.remove(['notionIdentity', 'user'])
      }
    })
  }
  
  setupAuthListener()
```

When `onAuthStateChange`'s callback occurs on `SIGNED_IN` event, I got an `access_token`, but there is no `provider_token` that I need.

[image]

Comment: Hey Matt,

Not too familiar with chrome extensions but a `SIGNED_IN` event is also  called on setSession and [does not save the provider token](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue-js/blob/master/src/GoTrueClient.ts#L807) - perhaps the session you are seeing results from the SIGNED_IN event from setSession? Is there any chance you'd be able to save the provider token before calling setSession

Comment: @JoelLee thanks for cheking. It seems like [_saveSession](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue-js/blob/d67c14133212c419c8901f1364dcf0bd5137dc48/src/GoTrueClient.ts#L229) saves `provider_token`. I have no idea how I can save the provider token before calling setSession.